# Stop PHP executing <? within javascript

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to implement TinyMCE, which is working fine on my test rig, but on the production server, PHP is trying to execute some `'<?'` tags which are in the `tiny_mce.js` file.

I have a file called `html_editor.php`, which is brought into each form which requires it using `include_once`.  Inside `html_editor`, i have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Public/TinyMCE/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

followed by the Tiny MCE initialization, but it's failing on that line with `unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`.
I replaced the script file with `tiny_mce_src.js` to find the exact code which is causing the problem, and it's:

```
html.push('<?', name, ' ', text, '?>');
```

I've swapped the single quotes with doubles in `tiny_mce_src.js`, which does resolve the problem, but in the minified code, they're already double.

It's obviously a configuration difference with PHP between my test and production servers, but I can't track down what.  I am testing with PHP 5.3, and the server is running 5.2.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're letting your PHP server process your .js files?  That's not a super-great idea, as it'll mean they may not be cached by the clients, which really can slow pages down.

Comment: @Pointy, thats why you set the Cache using the `Header` function. Granted, not that writing js should be done this way, but yea.

Comment: Well, if you can force the files to be cached, why would you need to process them through PHP in the first place? If they're really dynamic, then you *can't* let them be cached. If they're *not* dynamic, why load your server down with pointless work?

Comment: Thats a good point. About all I can say is that if you want customizations to be made through an Admin Panel, IE just enter in hex code for color changing or other items like that, it would be good to set it up that way and have a re-cache of the file. Granted, that should be done in CSS, but still can hold true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are JavaScript files going through the PHP interpreter?!

Fix your server configuration to only treat `*.php` as PHP.  How to do this depends on the web server you use and how you're running PHP; can you paste your test and production configurations?

Comment: It's running on Apache.  I don't have access to the main .htaccess file, so I'll set one up in the /Scripts folder until I can get the admin to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit php.ini and set

```
short_open_tag=0
```

this will stop

being processed, its a good idea regardless, then make suer all your php scripts use

Comment: While it's true that this will make his problem go away, the real issue is that `.js` files are being parsed as php. See @Eevee's answer. If the TinyMCE had a line like `html.push('<?php', name, ' ', text, '?>');` then turning off short tags wouldn't help.